# Image resource release in c# application

Tags: c#, image, resources

I am doing an image processing project using Windows Forms (c#). You can see the design of my application below.
What does this app do : take the original image, create a copy and modify the copy.

My app is working well but, if I process the same original image another time without closing the app, I get an error due to (I think) the display of the modified image. I think that the display on the bottom right corner uses the resources of the image and, when I try to modify it again, the system considers that the image is already used by another program so it can't be modified.

So my question is : "How can I stop using the modified image if the user clicks on PROCESS again ?"
I tried to use the .Dispose() method but it didn't work.

Code of the c# function linked to the PROCESS button :

```
private async void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // start the waiting animation
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;


        if (csI != csP)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The selected profil does not match the selected image. Colorspaces are different.", "WARNING", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        else
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
            if (checkBox2.Checked == false)
            {
                rendered = false;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                await Task.Run(() => wrapper.DominantColors(trackBar1.Value, rendered));
                //wrapper.DominantColors(trackBar1.Value, rendered);
            }
            else
            {
                rendering = comboBox1.Text;
                string outputImage = wrapper.Link(rendering, bpc);
                rendered = true;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                await Task.Run(() => wrapper.DominantColors(trackBar1.Value, rendered));
                //wrapper.DominantColors(trackBar1.Value, rendered);
            }

            // re-enable things
            button8.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Visible = false;

            MessageBox.Show("processing done");
            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(imgDstPath);
            float WidthImg = bit.Width;
            float HeightImg = bit.Height;
            float alpha = WidthImg / pictureBox2.Width;
            float beta = HeightImg / pictureBox2.Height;
            alpha = Math.Max(alpha, beta);
            float newWidthf = WidthImg / alpha;
            float newHeightf = HeightImg / alpha;
            int newHeight = (int)newHeightf;
            int newWidth = (int)newWidthf;
            pictureBox2.ClientSize = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
            pictureBox2.Image = bit;
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            
        }
        
        

    }
```

If possible, I'd like to clear the use of the resources when I click on the process button.

Thank you in advance for your help

[image: Design of the application]

Comment: Show some code. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited so now you have the code of the process function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic rule is that all objects you create that implements `IDisposable` need to be disposed. When writing winforms apps all controls added to a forms are disposed when the form is disposed. But whenever you change things you might need to handle disposal yourself.

For example:

```
pictureBox2.Image = bit;
```

If `pictureBox2.Image` is already set to something you need to ensure that it is disposed.

```
var oldImage = pictureBox2.Image;
pictureBox2.Image = bit;
oldImage.Dispose();
```

I'm not sure this is the actual problem you are having, your example code is insufficient to make that determination. To discover this you need to debug your program! Start by examining your exceptions, does it fail when opening a file or some other resource? Where was that resource created? where is it disposed? Perhaps even use a memory debugger to produce a list of all objects that are alive to see if there are any suspicious objects kept around. Will disposal correctly occur if any arbitrary code throws an exception?

It is sometimes useful to check the identity of objects in the debugger, to see if it has been switched out, or see what object your breakpoint was triggered in. You can rightclick an object in the watch panel in visual studio and select "Make ObjectId", this will associate a number with the object that appears at the end of the value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will make a deeper investigation.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future wants to know the solution I found, here it is :
At the beginning of the PROCESS function I added those simple lines :

```
if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
                pictureBox2.Image = null;}
```

Comment: You should probably save the old image ref in a variable, then set `pictureBox2.Image` to `null` and only _then_ dispose it from the variable you made, otherwise there is a very slim chance the UI will try to paint the disposed image.